# NGXS Storage plugin breaks navigation

Tags: angular, routes, rxjs, ngxs

I am wondering, why the ngxs redirects to homepage when another page is being reloaded? I see in console RouterCancel events. It happens only if ngxs/storage plugin is installed. To reproduce: go to Profile page and click the browser page reload button.
Here is an example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-repro-4x6vcv

I use the latest version of ngxs/storage plugin which is 3.5.1.
There are similar questions on the internet, but with the older version.
As I found in the internet, it says that the error is fixed in version 3.5.1, but I am still facing it.

What is the actual problem?

Comment: Could you create an issue in our github repository?